# Use array key in value's function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I want an associative array object of the string of an HTML element's name to the hidden input element.  Like so...

```
var fieldNames2inputElements = {
    'FirstName' : document.getElementsByName('FirstName')[0],
    'LastName'  : document.getElementsByName('LastName')[0],
    ...
};
```

I'm already shaking my head at myself, knowing there's got to be a more DRY way of doing this.  Any suggestions?  How do I use the string key of an associative array as a parameter of something in the value for that key?

BTW: I don't have control of the hidden input elements having this name attribute versus an id or some other way of selecting it.

Comment: The least you touch the DOM the better as per performance. Hence you should do only two `document.querySelectorAll()` operations, one for each firstname and lastname. Then using `Array.prototype.map.call(firstNames, c => {...});` and then the same for the `lastNames` is one way of doing this job.

Answer (score 5):

You could define a helper function that accepts name of the target elements and returns an object:

```
function getByName(names) {
   return names.reduce(function(ret, name) {
       ret[name] = document.querySelector('input[name="'+ name +'"]');
       return ret;
   }, {});
}

var fieldNames2inputElements = getByName(['FirstName', 'lastName', '...']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write (with es6 arrow functions):

```
var fieldNames2inputElements = ['FirstName', 'LastName']
  .reduce((o, name) => (o[name] = document.getElementsByName(name)[0], o), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop, `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"input[name$=Name][type=hidden]"` as parameter

```js
for (var i = 0, elems = document.querySelectorAll("input[name$=Name][type=hidden]")
     , fieldNames2inputElements = {}
     ; i < elems.length; i++) {
  fieldNames2inputElements[elems[i].name] = elems[i]
};
console.log(fieldNames2inputElements)
```

```html
<input name="FirstName" type="hidden" />
<input name="LastName" type="hidden" />
```